# How can I sort a Log-File by its informations?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

How can I insert an Item into an array at the correct position?
I want to sort a Log file by its informations:

```
Line 1: 2019/06/28 Hello:world id:2346
Line 2: 2019/06/28 Hello:life id:3774
Line 3: 2019/06/25 Hello:world id:1643
             ^          ^         ^
           Pos[0]     Pos[1]    Pos[2]
```

How can i sort those Lines by only having the position of the information?

Comment: @ProgrammersJonas, can you provide an example of your input/output?

Comment: Input: File / List (one object is one line) + Position of Information (as shown in my question)

Comment: so do you want to sort by `id`? Are you allowed to use external libraries as pandas?

Comment: for the above input what do you expect as output

Comment: The output can be a sorted list, so in can print it with a for loop

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Yes i am, but i would like to have it as easy as possible :)

Comment: `sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line.split()[2])`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom key function to sort a list in a custom way:

```
def keyfn(line):
    date, hello, id_ = line.strip().split()
    _, num = id_.split(":")
    return int(num)

sorted_list = sorted(lines, key=keyfn)
```

This assumes that there are no additional spaces, such that there are always exactly 3 fields.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to do num.rstrip() to strip new line characters if any?

Comment: @pvpkiran Not really necessary in this case.